# Automate Heroku CLI login

Tags: bash, heroku, command-line-interface

I'm developing a bash script to automatic clone some projects and another task in dev VM's, but we have one project in Heroku and repository is in it. In my .sh file I have:

```
> heroku login
```

And this prompt to enter credentials, I read the "help" guide included on binary and documentation but I can't found anything to automatic insert username and password, I want something like this:

```
> heroku login -u someUser -p mySecurePassword
```

Exist any way similar to it?

Comment: Don't use Heroku as your code repository! Heroku currently permits users to clone from its Git interface, but this is [provided as a courtesy](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app). Heroku is _not_ a code repository. It's a platform-as-a-service host. You should use a repository service to host your repository.

Comment: Wow wow, thanks, only I follow their instructions. I have a question.. when I run heroku git:clone -a myapp this command is inside git folder (myapp)? and what is the result? change git url? (sorry for my questions, documentation is so general)

Comment: Now I'm confused. If you already have a folder `myapp` containing your application there's no point in running `heroku git:clone -a myapp`. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: " What are you trying to accomplish?": I want to login into Heroku without email and password prompt

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The Heroku CLI [only uses your username and password to retrieve your API key](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#getting-started), which it [stores in your `~/.netrc` file](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/authentication#api-token-storage) (`%HOMEPATH%\_netrc` on Windows).

You can manually retrieve your API key and add it to your `~/.netrc` file:

1. Log into the Heroku web interface
2. Navigate to your **Account settings** page
3. Scroll down to the **API Key** section and click the **Reveal** button
4. Copy your API key
5. Open your `~/.netrc` file, or create it, with your favourite text editor
6. Add the following content:

   ```
    machine api.heroku.com
      login <your-email@address>
      password <your-api-key>
    machine git.heroku.com
      login <your-email@address>
      password <your-api-key>
   ```

   Replace `<your-email@address>` with the email address registered with Heroku, and `<your-api-key>` with the API key you copied from Heroku.

This should manually accomplish what `heroku login` does automatically. **However, I don't recommend this.** Running `heroku login` does the same thing more easily and with fewer opportunities to make a mistake.

If you decide to copy `~/.netrc` files between machines or accounts you should be aware of two major caveats:

- This file is used by [many](https://linux.die.net/man/5/netrc) [other](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.networkcomm/tcpip_netrc.htm) [programs](https://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/manual/html_node/The-_002enetrc-file.html); be careful to only copy the configuration stanzas you want.
- Your API key offers [full programmatic access to your account](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference). You should protect it as strongly as you protect your password.

Please be very careful if you intend to log into Heroku using any mechanism other than `heroku login`.

Comment: OTOH this is (AFAICT) the only way to use `heroku` CLI in CI/CD settings.

Comment: this was very useful to me because I didn't realize I can just provide my API key from https://dashboard.heroku.com/account as the "password" for `heroku login` (even without using .netrc, for the reasons you said). Seems like the heroku CLI should make this more clear...

Answer (score 14):

You can generate a non-expiring OAuth token then pass it to the CLI via an environment variable. This is useful if you need to run Heroku CLI commands indefinitely from a scheduler and you don't want the login to expire. Do it like this (these are not actual Tokens and IDs, BTW):

```
$ heroku authorizations:create
Creating OAuth Authorization... done
Client:      <none>
ID:          80fad839-876b-4ea0-a41e-6a9a2fb0cf97
Description: Long-lived user authorization
Scope:       global
Token:       ddf4a0e5-9294-4c5f-8820-b51c52fce4f9
Updated at:  Fri Aug 02 2019 21:26:09 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) (less than a minute ago)
```

Get the token (*not* the ID) from that authorization and pass it to your CLI:

```
$ HEROKU_API_KEY='ddf4a0e5-9294-4c5f-8820-b51c52fce4f9' heroku run ls --app my-app
Running ls on ⬢ my-app... up, run.2962 (Hobby)
<some file names>
$
```

By the way this also solves the problem of how to use the Heroku CLI when you have MFA enabled on your Heroku account but your machine doesn't have a web browser e.g., if you are working on an EC2 box via SSH:

```
$ heroku run ls --app my-app
heroku: Press any key to open up the browser to login or q to exit:
 ›   Error: quit
$ HEROKU_API_KEY='ddf4a0e5-9299-4c5f-8820-b51c52fce4f9' heroku run ls --app my-app
Running ls on ⬢ my-app... up, run.5029 (Hobby)
<some file names>
$
```

##### EDIT: For Windows Machines

After you run `heroku authorizations:create`, copy the "Token", and run the following commands:

```
set HEROKU_API_KEY=ddf4a0e5-9299-4c5f-8820-b51c52fce4f9
heroku run ls --app my-app
```

Comment: is there any difference between the API key that you generate with `heroku authorizations:create` and the API key on https://dashboard.heroku.com/account? For instance, does the one on the dashboard expire more frequently?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that *Heroku* should have by now provided a way to do this with their higher level CLI tool.

You can avoid extreme solutions (and you should, just like Chris mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46365185/989991)) by simply using *curl* and the [Heroku API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference). *Heroku* allow you to use your *API Token* (obtainable through your user settings / [profile page](https://dashboard.heroku.com/account) on the *Heroku* dashboard).

You can then use the API to achieve whatever it is you wanted to do with their command line tool.

For example, if I wanted to get all config vars for an app I would write a script that did something like the following:

````
-H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_TOKEN```

If *YOUR_APP_NAME* had only one config variable called *my_var* the response of the above call would be 

    { 
        "my_var": some_value
    }

I've found using this all the time in CI tools that need access to *Heroku* information / resources.
````

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is just to **get the source code**, you could use a simple git client. You just need the **api key**.

## Steps to get api key

- Log into the Heroku web interface
- Navigate to your Account settings page
- Scroll down to the API Key section and click the Reveal button
- Copy your API key

## Download source code using git

Use this url template for git clone

```
https://my_user:my_password@git.heroku.com/name_of_your_app.git
```

In my case the **user** value was my email without **domain**.

```
Example : 
if mail is **duke@gmail.com**
user for heroku auth will be **duke**
```

Finally just clone it like any other git repositories:

```
git clone https://duke:my_password@git.heroku.com/name_of_your_app.git
```