# VSTS Pipelines, how to answer to a cmd prompt?

Tags: node.js, heroku, cmd, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I wanted to login to Heroku cli using Visual Studio Team Services release pipelines, the cmd line to login to Heroku is:

```
heroku login
```

Executing that command, Heroku cli will prompt this:

```
Email:
Password:
```

I don't know how to automate the inputs for that prompt, I would like to write a command or bash to login every time the task is executing.

**EDITED** 
If it was from another platform, for example Github, then how do I automate a cmd prompt?

Screenshots:

[My pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjChY.png)

[Results from Heroku Cli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uekSG.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automate Heroku CLI login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46290445/automate-heroku-cli-login)

Comment: But how do I automate it with azure-pipelines?

Comment: Maybe the VSTS extension "Heroku Release Tools" https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=boostingmy.vsts-heroku-tasks ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way it's to provide the credentials inline, for example, if you want to clone a Git repo from GitHub:

```
git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git
```

In Heroku case is impossible because they don't support this way. you can accomplish the accomplish `heroku login` by edit the `~/.netrc` file - find the way in the above-provided answer.

But - you can try to answer the prompt automatically in this way:

```
(
  echo "EMAIL" 
  echo "PASSWORD"
) | heroku login
```