# Heroku login cannot open browser

Tags: ubuntu, heroku, heroku-cli

When attampting to login to Heroku via the CLI, I get:

```
user@MyMachine:$ sudo heroku login 
heroku: Press any key to open up the browser to login or q to exit: 
Opening browser to https://cli-auth.heroku.com/auth/browser/SOME-HEROKU-TOKEN
Warning: Cannot open browser.
heroku: Waiting for login... !
```

And the login hangs while waiting for the browser.
When I open the link in the browser and try to login, nothing happens in the CLI.

Using the debugging flags yields:

```
user@MyMachine:~$ sudo HEROKU_DEBUG=true HEROKU_DEBUG_HEADERS=1 heroku login 
heroku: Press any key to open up the browser to login or q to exit: 
Opening browser to https://cli-auth.heroku.com/auth/browser/SOME-OTHER-TOKEN
Warning: Cannot open browser.
    at Object.warn (/snap/heroku/3776/node_modules/@oclif/errors/lib/index.js:33:15)
    at showUrl (/snap/heroku/3776/node_modules/@heroku-cli/command/lib/login.js:132:34)
    at ChildProcess.cp.on.code (/snap/heroku/3776/node_modules/@heroku-cli/command/lib/login.js:145:17)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:193:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:999:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:266:5)
heroku: Waiting for login... !
JSONError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near ' '
    at module.exports (/snap/heroku/3776/node_modules/parse-json/index.js:26:19)
    at HTTP._parse (/snap/heroku/3776/node_modules/@heroku-cli/command/node_modules/http-call/lib/http.js:343:25)
```

And again, a hang.

Comment: I don't know clearly why, but "heroku login -i" works well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to solve this by:

1. Running as root - `sudo su`
2. Adding the `/snap/bin` folder to my `PATH` - `PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin`
3. Doing `heroku login`, copying the link into a browser, pressing login

This leaves me properly connected in the CLI, for some reason.
If someone can shed some light on this that would be cool.

Answer (score 44):

Heroku is currently under update but try this should work: `heroku login -i`

Comment: Thanks this helped! I noticed that the command `heroku login -i` is documented, but when I searched for `Warning: Cannot open browser.` I ended up here.

Comment: this saved me lots of time, working still January 2021

Answer (score 0):

You can also generate a non-expiring OAuth token and pass it to the CLI via an environment variable. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46290445/automate-heroku-cli-login/57333180#57333180) for how to do it. You may already have an API key. Check in your Heroku web dashboard under Account Settings > Account > API Key.

Answer (score 0):

Windows user here, switching from git bash to windows cmd worked for me, using just heroku login.