# How to stop Heroku CLI automatically logging me out?

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

After running `heroku login` on my work account, and putting work away for the weekend, each Monday I am told that I must log in again when running `heroku` commands.

This doesn't seem to happen for anybody else at the office, and nobody knows quite how or why. The Heroku documentation doesn't appear to be very helpful on the matter.

Does anybody know how I can stay logged in until I explicitly type `heroku logout`?

Comment: I've never seen this. As far as I know, `heroku login` [simply saves your API key to your `~/.netrc` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46365185/354577). Do you have a `~/.netrc` file? Does it look like it contains a valid API key? What operating system are you on?

Comment: macOS 10.14.6 (18G9216) — there is a `~/.netrc` now, but I can't swear that it was there before, though I suppose it must have been. I wonder if something caused the existing key to be invalidated…

Comment: @JohnY Did you ever end up finding out why you got logged out? I too was suddenly logged out and can't tell why... Wondering if it's a security issue.

Comment: I think, in my case, it's an organisation policy that sets a maximum session time. I have to log in to the web UI on a daily basis due to this.